# Triggering wxPython Radio button event from a different python script

Tags: wxpython, radio-button

I made a GUI, to control an electronic instrument I designed, which has different buttons for different states. I also made a python script to control that instrument. What I want to do is that when  I send a command to the instrument to change its state, the GUI should also show the change by changing the radio button selection. I just want to trigger the radio button click event externally from a different file. Is it possible?

Thanks,

Jatin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wx.Post event, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747781/wxpython-calling-an-event-manually), for example.

Personally, I find it easier to directly set the radio button gui using [SetValue](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.RadioButton-class.html#SetValue), and then directly call the handler (that you set in the Bind statement).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using PubSub ( http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/ ) or wx.PostEvent for that sort of thing.