# wxpython simulating bitmap button click

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I am trying to simulate a button click of a bitmap button. The code throws no errors and does nothing...

```
self.buttonImage = wx.Bitmap(button_image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
self.button = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, self.buttonImage, pos=(100, 300), style = wx.NO_BORDER)

evt = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId, self.button.GetId())
wx.PostEvent(self, evt)
```

Answer (score 1):

[A matching answer has been given already in another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786903) Assuming you are in the same thread (which should be the most common case in wxPython) you have to replace the `self` in `PostEvent` with something relating to the button. And of course your posted event will result in nothing, because you did not bind an event to the bitmap button.

```
# button creation
self.button = wx.BitmapButton(pnl, -1, self.buttonImage, pos=(100, 300), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
# Bind an event
self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)

# GUI test code
testbtn = frm.button # the button to be tested
evt = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId, testbtn.GetId())
wx.PostEvent(testbtn, evt) # try frm instead of testbtn and it will not work
```