# How to fire an wx.EVT_CLOSE from an inner panel

Tags: wxpython

I'm building a wxPython application.
The main frame includes a main panel.
The main panel include other panels.
In one of those panels there is an "Exit" button.
I want the application to close when I press the "Exit" button.
For that, I require to fire a wx.EVT_CLOSE to the main frame of the application. How do I fire that event?
Any other ideas are most welcome too.
Thanks in advance.

I'm adding the example below to show the case:

```
    import wx

    class MainScene(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainScene, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
        self.InitUI()

       def InitUI(self):
       # Define Master Panel
           masterPanel = wx.Panel(self)
           masterPanel.SetBackgroundColour("gold")
           horzbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
          subPanel=SubPanel(parent=masterPanel, size=(200, 200))

    class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
       def __init__(self, parent, size):
           wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
           self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
           vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
           exit_button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
           exit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
           vbox.Add(exit_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=5)
           self.SetSizer(vbox)

       def onClose(self, event):       
           self.Destroy()

    def main():
       app = wx.App()
       mainFrame = MainScene(None, title='Melanoma Buster')
       mainFrame.Show()
       app.MainLoop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u70V.png)

And this is after the click on the Exit button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NObtF.png)

Comment: hard to tell without seeing your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wx.Window.Close()` method. This method triggers the `wx.CloseEvent` for you. Take a look at the code below for a way to implement this.

For more details (and some limitations) about the Close() method take a look [here](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html?highlight=wx.window#wx.Window.Close) and for a way to use your custom event check these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747781/wxpython-calling-an-event-manually).

Code:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="Exit button",size=(200,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Exit", pos=(50, 50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

    def OnExit(self,event):
        """
        According to the wxPython docs self should refer to a top level window.
        This is important in your case because according to your question you
        have a nested GUI. So make sure self is the frame containing everything 
        in your window
        """
        self.Close(force=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
else:
    pass
```

EDIT BASED ON QUESTION UPDATE

You can place the `Destroy()` call either in the `MainScene` class or in the `SubPanel` class. When to use one or the other depends on whether the Exit button is something particular to the `MainScene` class (then I would put the `Destroy()` call in the MainScene class) or is something that the `SubPanel` class should always do (then I would put the `Destroy()` call in the `SubPanel` class).

`Destroy()` call in `MainScene` class:

```
import wx

class MainScene(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(MainScene, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
    self.InitUI()

  def InitUI(self):
    # Define Master Panel
    masterPanel = wx.Panel(self)
    masterPanel.SetBackgroundColour("gold")
    horzbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    subPanel=SubPanel(parent=masterPanel, size=(200, 200))

    subPanel.exit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Close)

  def Close(self, event):
    print('Called from MainScene')
    self.Destroy()

class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, size):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
    self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.exit_button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
    vbox.Add(self.exit_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=5)
    self.SetSizer(vbox)

def main():
  app = wx.App()
  mainFrame = MainScene(None, title='Melanoma Buster')
  mainFrame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

`Destroy()` call from `SubPanel` class:

```
import wx

class MainScene(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(MainScene, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
    self.InitUI()

  def InitUI(self):
    # Define Master Panel
    masterPanel = wx.Panel(self)
    masterPanel.SetBackgroundColour("gold")
    horzbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    subPanel=SubPanel(parent=masterPanel, size=(200, 200), mainWin=self)

class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, size, mainWin):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
    self.mainWin = mainWin
    self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    exit_button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
    exit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
    vbox.Add(exit_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=5)
    self.SetSizer(vbox)

  def onClose(self, event): 
    print('Called from SubPanel')      
    self.mainWin.Destroy()

def main():
  app = wx.App()
  mainFrame = MainScene(None, title='Melanoma Buster')
  mainFrame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just like in Rolf's answer, the event of the button is bind to the main frame while in my code the exit button is in a different class.

Comment: This is why is always a good idea to give a minimal working example (MWE) in the question. It helps you to get the answer you need faster. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ItayKrisher Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (check mark in the top left). Doing this allows focussing on questions with no accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Destroy`?
An object example in why your code sample is important, when asking a question.

You can still use `Destroy` but simply specify what is to be destroyed.
Because you have specified that `SubPanel` has the `parent` `masterPanel` the object to be destroyed is `self.GrandParent`. However, if you made the `parent` of `SubPanel` `self`, then you could use `self.Parent.Destroy()`.

```
import wx

class MainScene(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainScene, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 300))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
    # Define Master Panel
        masterPanel = wx.Panel(self)
        masterPanel.SetBackgroundColour("gold")
        horzbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        subPanel=SubPanel(parent=masterPanel, size=(200, 200))

class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        exit_button = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        exit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
        vbox.Add(exit_button, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Close()
        self.GrandParent.Destroy()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    mainFrame = MainScene(None, title='Melanoma Buster')
    mainFrame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The difference between your code and mine is that in your code the event of the Exit button is bind with the main frame of the program while in my code the sub-panel is a different class and therefore cannot be bind with the main frame. That's why I'd like to propagate an event upwards in the hierarchy.

Comment: See my amended response.